# windows 10 keyboard shortcut to mirror display

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, display, mirror

My laptop's screen stopped working suddenly. I connected another display to the laptop using HDMI. How can I mirror/duplicate to extended display with keyboard shortcut only, as current screen is not working. Then I can look into the issues.

OS: windows 10

Thanks.

Comment: Wrong site, I'm afraid. You're looking for [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support. You can find more info about this site in the [help].

Answer (score 6):

Hold Windows key, P to show dialog of mode selection, then P again to switch mode and release Windows key. This way you'll cycle modes, eventyally getting to projector mode.